# Using Xpath in python SAX module

Tags: python

I am parsing a very big XML file (50 GB) using python with the SAX module to extract some elements and attributes. I have done a lot of my code. I wanna know if I can use XPATH in this module
 or something like that to print the contents of the path `Rs/ Sequence/ Observed` and ignore the contents of the Observed tag in other paths.

Any tip, suggestion, or example about how to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

the parser object may have custom methods and variables to keep the status of the parsing.

so try something like this:

```
class RsParser(?):
    inRs = 0
    inSequence = 0
    depth = 0
    depthRs = 0
    depthSequence = 0

    def start(**kw):
        self.depth += 1
    def end(**kw):
        self.depth -= 1
    def startRs(**kw):
        self.inRs = 1
        self.depth += 1
        self.depthRs = self.depth
    def endRs(**kw):
        self.inRs = 0
        self.depth -= 1
    def startSequence(**kw):
        self.inSequence = 1
        self.depth += 1
        self.depthSequence = self.depth
    def endSequence(**kw):
        self.inSequence = 0
        self.depth -= 1
    def startObserved(**kw):
        self.depth += 1
        if self.inSequence and self.inRs and \
                self.depthRs == self.depth - 2 and \
                self.depthSequence = self.depth - 1:
            print "in RS/Sequence/Observed"
        else:
            print "in another observed"
```

hope this would help you